# Cheapest way to get from Zurich to Elba Island, Italy?

Tags: public-transport, international-travel, italy, zurich

I have to be in Elba from 9/2/2012 until 9/8/2012. I checked for various ways to get there. It seems that flying is not really an option since I can't find flights from these airports that are close to Zurich:

ZRH, ACH, FDH, BSL, MLH, FMM, SXB, LUG, STR, FKB

There seems to be a flight from Berne to Elba by Sky Work AG, but it costs more than 600 franks and I have never every heard of this airline before.

So I also tried to check the train schedule to see if I can take the train to Pisa, Italy and then take a bus and ferry to Elba. Unfortunately, the Swiss rail homepage seems not to be able to handle this kind of request.

Are there any other cheap options to get to Elba?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a lot of googeling during the last few days and I finally found a more or less cheap flight. It seems that [Intersky](http://www.intersky.biz) has regular flights from Zurich to Elba. Unfortunately I couldn't find these flights neither on ebookers nor on some well-known matrix flight search engines.

However, [Interksy offers flights](http://isk.tikaero.com/default.aspx?ori=ZRH&des=EBA&dep=2012-09-02&ret=2012-09-14&adt=1&chd=0&inf=0&langculture=de-de&bLFF=false) starting at 112 Euros. So it is cheaper and faster than taking the train.

Answer (score 6):

The train station to look for is Piombino. From there, walk to Piombino Marittima where the ferry starts.

I found a ticket train from Zurich to Piombino at CHF 258. I don't know if it is the cheapest.

Comment: Did you find that using SBB.ch?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise price info would not have been available. But I choose today as journey date and did not select return trip.